# C++: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++

I have read most of the other posts with this title, but I could not find a solution.

I have three files (I know the whole program doesn't make any sense, it is just for test purposes):

main.cpp

```
#include "Animal.h"

Animal ape;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    ape.getRace();

    return 0;
}
```

Animal.h

```
class Animal{
    public:
        int getRace();
    private:
        int race;
};
```

Animal.cpp

```
#include "Animal.h"

Animal::Animal(){
    race = 0;
}

int Animal::getRace(){
    race = 2;
    return race;
}
```

When I run the main.cpp file I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Animal::getRace()", referenced from:
      _main in main-oTHqe4.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to compile and link `Animal.cpp` and `main.cpp` together, for example:

```
gcc main.cpp Animal.cpp
```

It looks like you are not linking against `Animal.o` (which the above command would do).

P.S. You also need to declare the default constructor that you are defining in `Animal.cpp`:

```
class Animal{
    public:
        Animal(); // <=== ADD THIS
        int getRace();
    private:
        int race;
};
```

Comment: the op probably needs some inclusion guards too to create safe code ... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the resolution, but when I run this command, I get a new error: `Animal.cpp:3:6: error: definition of implicitly declared default constructor
Animal::Animal(){
     ^
1 error generated.`

Comment: hehe, of course, how could I fail to see this :) Thanks @NPE.